# Theme multiple rendered nodes as item_list

Tags: 7, theming

I am retrieving/rendering multiple nodes successfully with the following code:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);

$rendered_nodes = node_view_multiple($nodes, 'custom_view_mode');

return render($rendered_nodes);
```

I would like these nodes to be rendered as an item list. I have attempted to set the #theme property of the array to 'item_list' but it does not seem to be working. What is the correct way to theme this array of nodes returned by node_view_multiple()?

Comment: code you show us your code where you set the `#theme` in the array?  that's where the problem most probably lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should render multiple nodes using an item list.

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
$build = array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#items' => array_filter(reset(node_view_multiple($nodes)), function(&$node) {
        if (!is_array($node)) {
            return false;
        }

        $node = drupal_render($node);
        return true;
    }),
);

return drupal_render($build);
```